# how to create cascading dropdownlists inside repeating group in infopath?

Tags: infopath

I have two dropdownlists that get their data from lists in a sharepoint site, I want to convert them into cascading dropdownlists but all my effort is useless, I got my dropdownlists in a repeating group, can be for this?

the lists are related by a lookup field in the second list.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, I let it here because someone can use it:

my problem was that I was using in the first dropdownlist the title in the two parts : value and displayName of the dropdownlist because the lookup field to relate the two lists is the title of the first list and I thought the relation was by this field but not, they are related by ID of the first list (sounds right); you have to let the value part = to the ID because this is the value is going to be used as filter in the second dropdownlist (exactly you have to add a filter that says group field equals to main-dropdownlist1 (this has to be the name of your first dropdown).

note: I also used to get the lists in the load event of the form (very strange but it is in the data section - formLoad , then you add rules to query data and load the lists here)